# Laravel 5 sboo\Multiauth setup for multisite project

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm trying to use [Laravel Multiauth Package](https://github.com/sboo/multiauth) but the documentation has no tutorial or guide to demonstrate the setup in the way i want to use it.

I have a **multisite** (two sites by now) project in which i want to have **separate login forms** for each site, both sites make use of the same database, same models, but different controllers, all actions are separated by **route groups**, each route group resolves to a specific domain, that being said, my questions are:

- Do i need to create an `AuthController`, a `PasswordController` and an `Authenticate` & `RedirectIfAuthenticated` Middlewares for each site?
- Will i have to make separate routes to authenticate for each route group?

Here are my route groups:

```
Route::group(array( 'domain' => 'restaurant.com', 'namespace' => 'Public' ), function () {
    //some routes
});

Route::group(array( 'domain' => 'restaurant.net', 'namespace' => 'Admin' ), function () {
    //some routes
});
```

When i follow the steps in the package documentation, it works, but only for admin users, not for public users, that's because in the documentation it's configured only for that, when it should demonstrate how to use the multiauth

If possible, could someone make a step by step to setup this under **Laravel 5** (not 5.1 or 5.2) please.

### UPDATE 1

So far what i've done is create separate`AuthController` and `PasswordController`, then i overrided the `getLogin()` and `getRegister` functions and the `$redirectTo` variable, but when trying to register a user i get an error message telling me:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'multisite.users' doesn't exist

It makes sense, there's no `users` table, but *multiauth* package docs says tells that we have to change the default **app/auth.php** like this:

```
return [

    'multi' => [
        'employee' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'Employees'
        ],
        'client' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'Clients'
        ]
    ],
    'password' => [
        'email' => 'emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],

];
```

So that i won't use users table... My applications namespace is `Multisite`, now my question is: why it looks for users table?

### UPDATE 2

I found why it looks for users table, the file **app/Services/Registrar.php** is configured for `Users`, if i switch it a model to Employees or Clients it works, but only for one model a time.

Now another question emerges: I'm telling at *config/auth.php* that i want to use database driver, that means i should not be getting this error, do i have to create my own post functions for each auth controller?